# Which Podcast best explains the rep and badge system on StackExchange?

Tags: discussion, gaming-the-system

I'm trying to explain the gamified system to a friend, and I've heard it discussed in several of the SE podcasts as an aside. Do any podcasts explain this concept directly? which one(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, [Podcast #23](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/se-podcast-23/) was primarily on the topic of gamification. I can't recall right now the specifics of the discussion, but it may be a good start based on what's mentioned in the show notes.